# Adding the a tag to img is ruining the style of my grid;

Tags: css, image

when i try to add the  tag to  it makes the image bigger and overlaps with the others.

i already tried adding an a element but it did nothing.

```
.image-grid a {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

heres the css

```
.image-grid {
        --gap: 16px;
        --num-cols: 4;
        --row-height: 300px;

        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: var(--gap);
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--num-cols), 1fr);
        grid-auto-rows: var(--row-height);
        gap: var(--gap);
    }

    .image-grid>img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }

    .image-grid a {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .image-grid img:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: 0.5;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .image-grid-col-2 {
        grid-column: span 2;
    }

    .image-grid-row-2 {
        grid-row: span 2;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
        .image-grid {
            --num-cols: 2;
            --row-heigth: 200px;
        }
    }
```

heres the html

```
<div class="image-grid">
        <img class="image-grid-col-2 image-grid-row-2" src="https://i.imgur.com/lGLKiVd.png" alt="Star of Libby P1">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/lGLKiVd.png" alt="Star of Libby P1"></a>
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/lGLKiVd.png" alt="Star of Libby P1">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/lGLKiVd.png" alt="Star of Libby P1">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/lGLKiVd.png" alt="Star of Libby P1">
    </div>
```

i wanted to have everything to work and styled just like if i didn't add the  tag on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line

```css
.image-grid>img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

The `>` between `.image-grid` and `img` means direct child of, so if you add a `a` tag between them this condition is not valid and the rule is not applied

You can do for example

```css
.image-grid img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Then the rule will apply in both cases

Answer (score 0):

If you apply `display: contents;` to that `a` tag, its child, i.e. in your case the `img` will be handled as if that `a` tag didn't exist (concerning position, size etc.), i.e. the way it was before you added the `a` tag.